# Как реализованы обучающая платформа Codecademy и ей подобные?

Tags: input

Кто может объяснить, как реализован ввод и обработка кода у обучающих сервисов вроде Codecademy.com и ей подобных?

С FreeCodeCamp более-менее ясно - там обрабатывается только html+css+js код. А вот у Codecademy обрабатывается и Java, и Ruby... Сомневаюсь, что они позволяют обрабатывать чужой код на своих серверах...

Есть ли готовые решения для этих целей, кто знает?

Comment: Ну если и не на своих серверах, то на чужих. Наверняка там выключено всё, что может привести к некорректной работе сервера

Comment: В виртуальной машине можно запускать любой код, виртуалка не сохраняется и каждый раз грузиться заново. Естественно все параметры ограниченны ее внутренностями.

Comment: Получается, они используют какие-то "серверные" версии виртуальной машины, заточенные каждая строго под свой язык? Иначе почему так быстро запросы обрабатываются - в считанные секунды.